# Changing ns2 code for MAC 802_3 to turn off collission detection

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, ns2

I've been working on ns2 simulations for the past few weeks and need to change the implementation in ns-2.35/mac/mac-802_3.cc to turn off collision detection.

This is the code that runs whenever a collision takes place -

```
void Mac802_3::collision(Packet *p) {

    PRNT_MAC_FUNCS(this);

    if (mhIFS_.busy()) mhIFS_.cancel();

    double ifstime= netif_->txtime(int((IEEE_8023_JAMSIZE+IEEE_8023_IFS_BITS)/8.0)); //jam time + ifs
    mhIFS_.schedule(ifstime);

    switch(state_) {
    case MAC_SEND:
      // If mac trace feature is on generate a collision trace for this packet. 
            if (trace_)
               drop(p);
            else
               Packet::free(p);
        if (mhSend_.busy()) mhSend_.cancel();
        if (!mhRetx_.busy()) {
            /* schedule retransmissions */
            if (!mhRetx_.schedule(ifstime)) {
                p= mhRetx_.packet();
                hdr_cmn *th = hdr_cmn::access(p);
                HDR_CMN(p)->size() -= (ETHER_HDR_LEN + HDR_MAC(p)->padding_);
                fprintf(stderr,"BEB limit exceeded:Dropping packet %d\n",th->uid());
                                fflush(stderr);
                drop(p); // drop if backed off far enough
                mhRetx_.reset();
            }
        }
        break;
    case MAC_RECV:
            Packet::free(p);
        // more than 2 packets collisions possible
        if (mhRecv_.busy()) mhRecv_.cancel();
        break;
    default:
        assert("SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN" == 0);
    }
}
```

I've tried commenting the .cancel() part to avoid cancelling the transmission when collision is detected. But this does not work as expected and I get zero throughput on the network. Can someone guide me on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: CSMA/CD is an integral part of IEEE 802.3, so disabling it makes it _not_ 802.3.

Comment: @RonMaupin That is exactly what I want to do to implement somewhat a replication of Mac/Csma , which is deprecated in ns2.35.

Comment: Turning off collision detection would require disabling CSMA/CD, which is the opposite. For CSMA/CD to work, you need a shared medium for all the hosts. A switched network ignores CSMA/CD.

Comment: @RonMaupin What I actually want to do is get an implementation of vanilla CSMA without any collission detection and then compare that with CSMA/CD and see how much the experimental results differ in both cases? Is this possible in current ns2 without any modifications to the source code ?

Comment: Again, without CSMA/CD, it is _not_ IEEE 802.3. CSMA really just means that there are multiple devices on a shared medium. That breaks without CD (IEEE 802.3) or CA (IEEE 802.11) because you just get garbage on the shared medium. Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) cannot do CD because a device cannot both send and receive at the same time, so it uses CA and ACKs to know that there was no collision without actually detecting the collision.

Comment: oh so you mean to say that CSMA alone without CA or CD will not at all able to trasmit packet effectively on the network due to no collision resolution techniques being applied. That clears things up. Thank you for the help. @RonMaupin

Comment: CSMA is Carrier Sense (is the interface up with a carrier?) Multiple Access (a shared medium). CD is Collision Detection to hear if a collision has happened, and CA is Collision Avoidance (to try to avoid a collision, but needs ACKs to determine if the frame got through). CD is much more efficient than CA, but you need something to try to avoid collisions or determine if a collision happened, otherwise every host will just stomp on every other host on the shared medium, resulting in garbage instead of frames.